# REST API Confusion

Tags: sql-server, database, api, rest

I'm trying to write a simple rest API to connect to my sql Server database and execute a simple query to retrieve data from a database.

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/voobans-tech-stories/how-to-quickly-create-a-simple-rest-api-for-sql-server-database-7ddb595f751a

Here's where my confusion lies:

The example has a server initialization file that looks like this:

```
var express = require('express'); // Web Framework
var app = express();
var sql = require('mssql'); // MS Sql Server client

// Connection string parameters.
var sqlConfig = {
    user: 'UserName',
    password: 'mot de passe',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'DatabaseName'
}

// Start server and listen on http://localhost:8081/
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port

    console.log("app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

It also has a select query the example uses on the customer table located in the database:

```
app.get('/customers', function (req, res) {
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function() {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('select * from Sales.Customer', function(err, recordset) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset)); // Result in JSON format
        });
    });
})
```

What I'm not understanding is how these two files are connected or interacting. At the end of the tutorial, the author says in order to test the example, copy the code into a file and run it. The example has 4 separate files though - am I putting them all into the same document?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can put all code snippets in the same file for your test. It will be the easiest way since they all using the `app` variable.

But if you want a bigger application, it's cleaner in multiple files. You can then use code from another file using an import like `require('./filename.js');`